# How to gain material by trading pieces?

Tags: tactics, captures, trading

So, I am learning the basics on trading pieces, but can someone please give me tips on the "Art of trading pieces with material gain".

I know a concept called overloading, but are there any other tactical concepts?

Comment: Are you asking for tactics that can be set up by making a trade a of pieces first? Such as the "Removing the Defender" motif?

Comment: Yes bad_bishop. Sorry for not explaining properly.

Comment: In that case, all of the tactical motifs can be preceded by a trade. Think about the Open Ruy Lopez, 1 e4 e5 2 Nf3 Nc6 3 Bb5 a6 4 Ba4 Nf6 5 O-O Nxe4 6 d4 exd4? 7 Re1. On move 6, Black blunders by trading, falling into a pin.

Answer (score 3):

[Substitution](http://www.chesstactics.org/index.php?Type=page&Action=back&From=5,1,1,1) would be another. With a trade/capture, you can set up another tactical motive like a skewer or a fork.

In the position below (taken from the ChessTactics link above), Black wins an exchange with the following combination:

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[StartFlipped "1"]
[FEN "2r2rk1/p1p1qp1p/1p2n1pb/8/n7/1PB1PBN1/P2Q1PPP/R4RK1 b - - 0 33"]

1... Nxc3 2. Qxc3 Bg7
```

Comment: This is very nice :J

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer but as you can't put pgns in comments:

While labelling tactical ideas helps in learning beware of putting them too much in separate boxes, they tend to blend into each other. For instance take the following:

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[FEN "2r1k2r/1pq2pp1/pn2p2p/2b1p3/4P2B/2N5/PP1Q1PPP/2RR2K1 w - - 0 1"]

1.Nb5 axb5 2.Rxc5 Qxc5 3.Qd8+ Rxd8 4.Rxd8# *
```

Is Rxc5 a deflection, exploiting the overloading of the queen or a skewer? I would argue it's a bit of all 3

Comment: It is also removal of the defender.  Could be viewed as a double attack, that is attacking the Queen and the mate square.